# Xamarin - MediaPicker not showing the videoPicker for iOS

Tags: c#, ios, mono, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I tried doing this in my main app I'm writing but can't seem to get it to work. So I created a Single View Application to try it out and figure it out but I still seem to be stuck. He's what i got.

```
public partial class HelloViewController : UIViewController
{
    partial class VideoPickerController : UIViewController
    {
        MediaPicker videoPicker;
        readonly TaskScheduler uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
        public VideoPickerController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
        }

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning ()
        {
            // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning ();

            // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();

            var picker = new MediaPicker ();

            PresentViewController (picker.GetPickPhotoUI (), true, null);


        }
    }
}
```

Basically all I get is a white screen and nothing happens. Thanks!

Comment: you have a VideoPickerController inside of HelloViewController, but you never create an instance of VideoPickerController or do anything with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need need to to manually present it. This is code that I used and it automatically presents the UI for me. This code is not in it's own viewcontroller, it is just in whatever viewcontroller that I have the button it to take the pic. There are similar methods for the photo album and for taking videos.

[Here](https://github.com/SparkhoundMobile/MobileTraining/tree/Camera) is a link to the github page where I have this sample app hosted.

```
var picker = new Xamarin.Media.MediaPicker();

btnCamera.Hidden = !picker.IsCameraAvailable;
btnCamera.TouchUpInside += async (sender, e) =>
{
    try
    {
        MediaFile file = 
            await picker.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions());
        processImage(file);
    }
    catch { }
};

btnPhoto.Hidden = !picker.PhotosSupported;
btnPhoto.TouchUpInside += async (sender, e) =>
{
    try
    {
        MediaFile file = await picker.PickPhotoAsync();
        processImage(file);
    }
    catch { }
};

private void processImage(MediaFile file)
{
    if (file != null)
    {
        viewModel.Image = file.GetStream();
        viewModel.ImagePath = file.Path;
        setImage();
    }
}

private void setImage()
{
    try
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(viewModel.ImagePath);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewModel.ImagePath) &&
            System.IO.File.Exists(viewModel.ImagePath))
        {
            imgImage.Image = new UIImage(NSData.FromFile(viewModel.ImagePath));
        }
        else if (viewModel.Image != null && viewModel.Image.Length != 0)
        {
            imgImage.Image = new UIImage(NSData.FromStream(viewModel.Image));
        }
    }
    //just don't load image
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. What is viewModel?

Comment: It is just a local variable for my view model since I'm using the MVVM pattern.

Comment: Okay so are you using MVVMCross?

Comment: No, I am not. My sample app was pretty simple so I just copied from james montemagno's sample apps (from xamarin) for the architecture for mine.

Comment: I added the link to my app on github. Check it out if you think it might help you.

Comment: Okay I managed to figure it out using the code provided! Thanks so much man!